# MySql Handler. Обработка ошибок в процедурах

Tags: mysql, исключения, procedure

Как можно обработать ошибки при дублировании id.Например узнать в каком ряде (INSERT) она возникла, есть ли такой подход ?

Я вот который день пытаюсь его реализовать все не получается. IF, CASE че только не пробовал

```
DROP TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE test(id INT,PRIMARY KEY (id));

DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE test |
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);

    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут приведен код который игнорирует дубликаты и записывает в переменную какое то сообщение при возникновении конкретной ошибки.

`SELECT @myError` покажет вам ее.

`SELECT @x` будет равен 3 поскольку были проигнорированы дубликаты и код дошел до конца.

На счет отловки в каком ряду возникла могу подсказать подход (Не пробовал).
Можно в цикле запустить и инициировать какую нибудь переменную в ++ . А потом при ошибке конкатенировать с error сообщением,ну или что то в этом вроде.

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test |
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET @myError = 'You have a error <Duplicate entry>';
    SET @x=1;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
    SET @x=2;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
    SET @x=3;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
END;
|
DELIMITER ;

CALL test();

SELECT @x;
SELECT @myError;
```

Если надо сделать какое то действие при возникновении ошибок то пользуйтесь IF ... ELSE

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test |
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET @x2=1;
    SET @x=1;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
    SET @x=2;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (2);
    SET @x=3;
    INSERT INTO test VALUES (3);

    IF @x2 = 1 THEN
        SELECT 0 AS id,'Dannix net' AS title;
    ELSE 
        SELECT *
            FROM tbl_name;
    END IF;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;

CALL test();
SELECT @x;
SELECT @x2;
```

Тут тоже почитайте полезная инфа  [DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html)

Comment: Крутой код.Спасибо